# How to get the 30th of the month after a given date

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date value varFinishDate that I pull form an SQL database and I want to get the 30th of the month after varFinishDate. Except if it’s going to be in February when I want it to be the 28th.  What is the best way to do this in C#?

To put it in context, we have programs running and the reports are due at the end of the month after they finish (on the 30th even if there are 31 days). So if it finished any time in April the report is due on the 30th of May and so on, except where they finish in January then the reports are due on the 28th of February.

Comment: As a curiosity, if it's Feb, why wouldn't you want the last day (i.e. 28 or 29)?

Comment: I think management just find it easier to ignore leap years for constancy “All reports are due on the 30th or on the 28th if it’s Feb”. The same reason they picked the 30th instead of the last day of each month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
var nextMonth = varFinishDate.AddMonths(1);
var targetDate = new DateTime(
    nextMonth.Year,
    nextMonth.Month,
    nextMonth.Month == 2 ? 28 : 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use DaysInMonth();

So you would have something like

```
var nextMonth = varFinishDate.AddMonths(1);
if(nextMonth.DaysInMonth() < 30)
   nextMonth = new DateTime(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month, 28);
else
    nextMonth = new DateTime(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int day = 30;
if (finishedDate.Month == 1)
    day = 28;

DateTime nextMonth = finishedDate.AddMonths(1);

DateTime reportDate = new DateTime(nextMonth.Year, nextMonth.Month, day);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should allow for leap years to also use day 29:

```
var dueDate = varFinishDate.AddMonths(1);
if ( DateTime.DaysInMonth(dueDate.Year, dueDate.Month) < 30 ) {
      dueDate.AddDays(DateTime.DaysInMonth(dueDate.Year, dueDate.Month) - dueDate.Day);
} else {
      dueDate = new DateTime(dueDate.Year,dueDate.Month,30);
}
```